# How to find xpath for text contains and select check box in that row using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, xpath, ide

I've 3 rows in my table and I want to select a check box that contains text 1024.0281. I can find text contains part number like this
xpath=//a[text()='1024.0281']

But I don't know how to select checkbox in that line, How to do that?
I'm trying to do this in Selenium IDE.
Thank you in advance!

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><input class=RightText name='DHR' type='checkbox' id='Chk_DHR0' value='1^310^0^^^^' onClick=javascript:fnCalcDHRAmt( 'Chk_DHR0',this.form) tabindex="8"><input type=hidden name='hDHRID0' value='GM-DHR-200789551'> <input type=hidden name='hVID0' value='334'>      <input type='hidden' value='0' name='hDHRAmtGMDHR200789551'></td>
    <td>PS-1876546</td>
    <td><a title="7.5mm REVERE HA Monoaxial Screw, 27mm">1024.0131</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td><input class=RightText name='DHR' type='checkbox' id='Chk_DHR1' value='1^465^0^^^^' onClick=javascript:fnCalcDHRAmt( 'Chk_DHR1',this.form) tabindex="9"><input type=hidden name='hDHRID1' value='GM-DHR-200789552'> <input type=hidden name='hVID1' value='334'>      <input type='hidden' value='0' name='hDHRAmtGMDHR200789552'></td>
    <td>PS-1876546</td>
    <td><a title="8.5mm REVERE HA Monoaxial Screw, 25mm">1024.0281</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><input class=RightText name='DHR' type='checkbox' id='Chk_DHR2' value='1^1000^0^^^^' onClick=javascript:fnCalcDHRAmt( 'Chk_DHR2',this.form) tabindex="10"><input type=hidden name='hDHRID2' value='GM-DHR-200789553'> <input type=hidden name='hVID2' value='334'>      <input type='hidden' value='0' name='hDHRAmtGMDHR200789553'></td>
    <td>PS-1876546</td>
    <td><a title="REVERE  4.5 Thoracic Lamina Hook, Narrow, Medium">1041.9902</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` which will select the `tr` based on `anchor text` and then find the input checkbox.

```
//tr[.//a[text()='1024.0281']]//input[@class='RightText']
```

Or use preceding

```
//a[text()='1024.0281']/preceding::input[@name='DHR'][1]
```

Comment: Hi may I know how to loop for selecting multiple part number ?